# Is there some sort of JSON DTD concept that can be used to map JSON REST APIs back to the client in a generic way using configuration?

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, dtd

I'm trying to allow a user to configure a generic connector to external REST APIs that return JSON.  I'd like to allow the user to be able to map properties from the API to properties in my app. Is there a standard JSON DTD that would allow a user to specify "this property in the json result maps to this property in the app..."?

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you are using json.net, you could add attributes to the properties like

```
    public class Videogame
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("release_date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

[JsonProperty Attribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm)

But you would probably want to have different objects to represent the external api response and your app domain, so maybe you should give a try to a tool like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Perhaps I should have specified more clearly...I'm looking to do this at run-time. So someone could create a connector to their API and configure the mapping in some sort of configuration screen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for a standard that is called [Swagger](http://swagger.io/). It's like a WSDL for soap. You can add a [Swashbuckle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle) plugin to do automatically generate Swagger in ASP.Net Web Api.

It generates a very nice testing screen with all properties and documentation and such + the definition itself. Last time I tried though, the auto-generators for the client code were not too good and I had to use RestSharp to directly access the url's. But it's still worth the effort to add it.

Maybe there are better clients now available as well, and perhaps you have a client in another language where the client works much better.